# DocuSign - Unable to convert document

Tags: docusignapi

We’re getting an error – “unable to convert document” for one of our clients on our multi-tenant server. I’ve had a rummage and it looks like that error is generated when you’re sending a file with an unexpected extension meaning that DocuSign doesn’t know how to convert it to a PDF ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771197/docusign-random-unable-to-convert-document-error](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771197/docusign-random-unable-to-convert-document-error)). What I’m failing to understand is how it can be working for some – it works for me on our multi-tenant server – but not others. Is there more to this than meets the eye or am I missing something?

```
Headers : X-RateLimit-Reset: 1573833600
X-RateLimit-Limit: 1000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 991
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: #####
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2019 15:20:40 GMT

Response stream : {
  "errorCode": "UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENT",
  "message": "System was unable to convert this document to a PDF. Unable to convert Document(2019.11.15_NDA - MyDocument) to a PDF. Error: UserId:##### IPAddress:##### Source:ApiRESTv2:FileType 15_nda - my document is ineligible for conversion."
}
```

Comment: if you try to go directly to DocuSign web app and upload the file - does it work?

Comment: this error can be a result of many different things, not just a bad extension

Comment: how are you encoding the document in your API call?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are setting the `fileExtension` attribute to `pdf` in the `document` object in your Envelopes::create call.

If you don't set it, DocuSign does some guessing, but setting the attribute explicitly is the way to go.